# Selenium IDE for firefox is generating deprecated code

Tags: selenium, junit

The IDE is generating deprecated code for JUnit 4/Selenium Remote Control, using `com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium`. What is the possible fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried Selenium Builder?

Comment: @djangofan I just tried it, I don't think there is a way to generate java code for Selenium Remote Control.